# how to remove the dot and colon in replace method using regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, datetime

I want this log function to remove the dot and colon

I'm working on my javascript
regular expression

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].replace(/:./g, ''))
```

my code only removes the colon but not the point

I try a different method

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].replace(/:/b./g, ''))
console.log(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].replace(/(:)(.)/g, ''))
console.log(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].replace(/:&./g, ''))
```

It always output this format *0510.654Z*

Does anybody know how?

I'm expecting the output log to remove the colon and point

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].replace(/:./g, ''))
```

Comment: Try this `new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].replace(/[:\.]/g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [character class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#types) you want to replace like this:

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].replace(/[:\.]/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your regex to `[.:]`

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].replace(/[.:]/g, ''))
```

`[]` defines a character class in regex. `[abc]` will match all of the a, b, and c in the string.